# How do I output a multidimensional hash in ERB files?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I need some help printing the values of my hash. In my "web.rb" file I have:

```
class Main < Sinatra::Base

    j = {}
    j['Cordovan Communication'] = {:title => 'UX Lead', :className => 'cordovan', :images => ['http://placehold.it/350x150','http://placehold.it/350x150','http://placehold.it/350x150']}
    j['Telia'] = {:title => 'Creative Director', :className => 'telia', :images => ['http://placehold.it/350x150','http://placehold.it/350x150','http://placehold.it/350x150','http://placehold.it/350x150']}


    get '/' do
        @jobs = j
        erb :welcome
    end
end
```

In "welcome.rb" I'm printing the values of the hash, but it doesn't work:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <h2><%=h job.title %></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's my error message:

```
NoMethodError at / undefined method `title' for #<Array:0x10c144da0>
```

Comment: When iterators does not output what you want try inspecting what `@jobs.each.to_a` outputs.

Answer (score 7):

Think what `@jobs` looks like:

```
@jobs = {
  'Cordovan Communication' => {
    :title => 'UX Lead', 
    :className => 'cordovan',
    :images => ['http://placehold.it/350x150','http://placehold.it/350x150','http://placehold.it/350x150']},
  'Telia' => {
    :title => 'Creative Director',
    :className => 'telia',
    :images => ['http://placehold.it/350x150','http://placehold.it/350x150','http://placehold.it/350x150','http://placehold.it/350x150']}
}
```

Then remember that `each` called on a hash passes a key and a value to the block, and you'll see that you have:

```
@jobs.each do |name, details|
  # On first step, name = 'Cordovan Communication', details = {:title => 'UX Lead', ...}
end
```

So what you want is probably:

```
<% @jobs.each do |name, details| %>  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <h2><%=h details[:title] %></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no automatic method creation for Ruby hashes, e.g., you can't call `job.title`, since there is no `title` method on `Hash` objects.  Instead you can call `job[:title]`.

<del>Also note that `@jobs` is a hash, not an array, so you probably want to call `@jobs.each_pair` rather than `@jobs.each`.  It's possible to use `@jobs.each`, but in this case it's not going to give you what you expect.</del>

Comment: `Hash#each` and `Hash#each_pair` are the same method. Check [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each).